# Detect mouse position when or immediately after div scroll

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, mouse-position

How can I detect where the mouse is positioned whenever I scroll? I can do this using a combination of onmousemove and scroll, but this seems like such a waste. I don't need to know where the mouse is before I scroll, only when I scroll - or perhaps even just right after I scroll. Please refer to my snippet below to see my attempt (event.clientY produces undefined) and please no jquery. Thanks.

```js
var clientY_display_element = document.getElementById("clientY_display");

document.addEventListener('scroll', show_position = function (event) {
  clientY_display_element.textContent = "event.clientY = " + event.clientY;
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 50px;
}

#content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);
}

#clientY_display {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="clientY_display">Scroll to see event.clientY position.. </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve? Scroll inside the #container to see the number of pixels scrolled.

clientY is the coordinate of the mouse pointer when a mouse event was triggered. But you are listening for "scroll" event which is triggered when the document view has been scrolled. For scroll events, you can use the scrollTop to get the number of pixels that an element's content is scrolled vertically.

I also changed a bit your css, for this example's purpose.

```js
var clientY_display_element = document.getElementById("clientY_display");
let scroller = document.querySelector("#container")

scroller.addEventListener('scroll', show_position = function (event) {
  clientY_display_element.textContent = `scroll position = ${scroller.scrollTop}`;
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);
}

#clientY_display {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="clientY_display">Scroll to see scroll position.. </div>
```